# Membership Based Warning: implode(): Invalid arguments passed

Tags: php, function, warnings, membership

I am having a problem with a Warning coming up when it has to do with Membership based logins on this domain: freeyogatv.com  When someone is logged in, things are going fine, but when it is the public html, I am getting a lot of different ""Warning: implode(): Invalid arguments passed""  as this seems to be based on the membership/login I am not sure where to go to rectify this code.  If it had to do with just one part of the code I feel my question would be easier, but I will include the code from one of the specific errors so that you might be able to point me in the right direction.  Please let me know and Thank you so very much!

```
<?php
/**
* The Sidebar containing the main widget areas.
 *
 * @package shanti
 */
?>
<div id="secondary" class="widget-area" role="complementary">
    <div id="donate-button-wrap">
        <?php $options = get_option( 'theme_settings' ); ?>
        <a href="<?php echo $options['donate_button_url']; ?>"     class="donate-button" target="_blank"><img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri() . '/images/donate.png'; ?>"/></a>
    </div>
    <?php do_action( 'before_sidebar' ); ?>
    <div id="widget-container">
        <div class="social-widget">
            <a href="<?php echo $options['facebook']; ?>"><span class="sidebar-social-icon social-icon">&#62221;</span></a>
            <a href="<?php echo $options['twitter']; ?>"><span class="sidebar-social-icon social-icon">&#62218;</span></a>
        </div>
        <?php if ( ! dynamic_sidebar( 'sidebar-1' ) ) : ?>
        <?php endif; // end sidebar widget area ?>
    </div>
    <div id="widget-container" class="login-widget-container">
        <?php if ( ! dynamic_sidebar( 'sidebar-2' ) ) : ?>
        <?php endif; // end sidebar widget area ?>
    </div>

    <!-- Hide the Sidebar ads if user is a premium member (specify user level ID from Theme options) -->
    <?php
    $premium_user_levels = $options['premium_user_levels'];
    $premium_user_levels_array = explode(',', $premium_user_levels);
```

// this is the error line I am receiving for this particular part of the website

```
    $user_meta = get_userdata(get_current_user_id());
    $user_role_array = implode(', ', $user_meta->roles);
    $user_role = explode(', ', $user_role_array);
    ?>
    <?php if($user_role[0] != 'administrator' AND $user_role[0] != 'contributor' AND !pmpro_hasMembershipLevel($premium_user_levels_array)) { ?>
        <div id="widget-container" class="ads-widget-container">
            <?php if ( ! dynamic_sidebar( 'sidebar-ads' ) ) : ?>
            <?php endif; // end sidebar widget area ?>
        </div>
    <?php } ?>

</div><!-- #secondary -->
```

I am currently at a loss, so:
Thank you Thank you Thank you!

Comment: There's only one implode() in the code you've posted. And you explode() that value right on the next line. Is that on purpose? Why?

Comment: try var_dumping whats you are imploding

Comment: It's not my code. This was my designers code and I am trying to fix a bug that came up after an update.  He is no longer available.